# TypeScript and dot-notation access to objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

If TypeScript is a strict superset of JavaScript, why is dot notation on an arbitrary object erroneous? I have JS code that I want to convert over to TS for better type safety, but all access using dot notation (eg, `myObj.thing`) gives me the error `Property 'thing' does not exist on type '{}'.`. It works properly when I use bracket notation (eg, `myObj['thing']`).

[image: Property does not exist on type]

Comment: That's a warning, it should still compile, so TypeScript is still a strict superset of JS. The reason it is warning you is because TypeScript is typed, and the type of `x` does not specify `bar` properties. You can either cast to `any`, apply an interface that does have `bar`, or use `["bar"]`.

Comment: @Asad: The error shown & described is reported as an error proper, not a warning, and my build fails. However, I am able to cast to `any` successfully.

Comment: TypeScript is intentionally more strict that JavaScript, so having it be legal in Javascript does not necessarily mean the TypeScript compiler will agree.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I know you say this is odd, but this is one of the main reasons TypeScript exists. This error helps prevent accidentally setting or getting non-existent properties on an object.

Right now, as the compiler is telling you, the property `bar` does not exist on `x` because it has been implicitly typed to `{}` when writing `var x = {};`.

You can tell the compiler that `x` has more than zero properties by explicitly defining the type:

```
var x: { foo?: string; bar?: string; } = {};
```

Now you can get or set `x.foo` and `x.bar` without the compiler complaining. In most cases, you would move this into an interface like so:

```
interface IFooBar {
    foo?: string;
    bar?: string;
}

var x: IFooBar = {};

x.foo = "asdf";  // ok
x.test = "asdf"; // error, as it should be
```

Some people are recommending you cast to `any`, but don't get lazy. You should make full use of the type system TypeScript provides. Doing so will most definitely save you time down the road as you maintain an application.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the strongly-typed nature of Typescript Object, you can use "any" to make it untyped:

```
var x: any = {};
x.bar = "bar";   /// ok
```

If what's you need is to define type of literal properties

```
var x: { [index: string]: TypeA } = {};
```

then `x["bar"]` can now only be instance of TypeA.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for tyty

Answer (score 0):

`x` does not hold any property named `bar` so you need create it within the object:

```
function foobar() {
    var x = {

        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar'
    }

    return x;
}

alert(foobar().bar); //returns bar
```

Comment: It's [apparently legal JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to assign to a property that doesn't exist yet in an object, so it seems odd that I can't do it in TS without a cast to `any` (as @Asad describes above).

Comment: Learning something new everyday... Multiple different ways to skin a cat,  i guess.

Answer (score 0):

mwilson got there before I could! ;)

In the code above, Typescript is unable to determine that the object `x` exposes a property called `bar` so cannot resolve it when displaying Intellisense.

Instead, add `foo`, `bar`, etc. as properties of the object itself:

```
var x = {
    foo: "FOO",
    bar: "BAR"
};
```

Then, when using the [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09foo%3A%20%22FOO%22%2C%0D%0A%09bar%3A%20%22BAR%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20p%20%3D%20document.createElement('p')%3B%0D%0Ap.textContent%20%3D%20x.%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(p)%3B%0D%0A), you'll be see the Intellisense work as expected:

[image]

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to specify types whenever I have the chance.

Note, that you can only instantiate this variable with `{}` if you define the fields as optional with the `?:` operator.

```
let x: {foo?: string, bar?: string} = {};
x.foo = 'foo';
x.bar = 'bar';
```

As others have said, if you plan to use this type multiple times, it's probably better to make an explicit class for it.

*PS: it's better to use `let` instead of `var` when programming in typescript. (e.g. the scope of a `var` declaration is a bit quirky, compared to a `let` which does what you expect it to do.)*